# Kivy: Mapping list of vertices

Tags: opengl, kivy

I show to you function from code for work with Kivy OpenGL. This part of code is source of my problem. After problem I tested next variants using parameter `fmt`:

1. `vertex_format`  =  `[('v_pos', 3, 'float')]` ->
    Exception: `expected byte, found str`
2. `vertex_format`  =  `[(b'v_pos', 3, 'float')]` ->
    no picture of scene on the screen
3. I don't use parameter `fmt` ->
    picture of scene has incorrect geometry

How must I correct code? Help me please!

```
def setup_scene(self):
    Color(1, 0, 1, 1)
    PushMatrix()
    self.rot = Rotate(1, 0, 1, 0)

    UpdateNormalMatrix()
    vertex_format = [('v_pos', 3, 'float')]
    self.mesh = Mesh(
        vertices=[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
        indices=self.indices,
        fmt=vertex_format,
        mode='lines'
    )

    PopMatrix()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```python
vertex_format = [(b'v_pos', 3, 'float')]
```

Comment: Yes, it is coincident to Kivy manual, but result is message "Unknown format type b'float' "

Comment: Thank You for your interest about my problem. I tested different example, bu my testing finished always by problem with format vertex. Can you send me  your code, which you used for testing? I am very nervous now from this.

Comment: @jasan try remove the b only from `b'float`. I updated.

Comment: I tested this before my question here. Result is without error, but black screen and none view on scene.

Comment: @jasan in your question the b is on the wrong side of (

Comment: You cann see to all code in question:  "KIvy: mapping list of vertices for using class Mash" on Stack Overflow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160951/discussion-between-jasan-and-el3phanten).